# How to edit the state in react using a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I followed [this React Tutorial](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/create-a-simple-todo-app-in-react-72d9341a7e6c) on how to create a simple toDo-App. Now I want to modify this app and add an "edit" function.

I try to edit the state using this.setState but the console.log shows that `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined`

My constructor:

```
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      currentItem: {
        text: '',
        key: '',
      },
    }
  }
```

My current edit function:

```
editItem = key => {
  console.log(key)
  console.log(this.state.text)
  this.setState({
    text: "edit"
  })
}
```

The correct key gets logged but nothing else works. `console.log(this.state.text)` returns `undefined`

So in my simple version pressing the edit button should change the text prop to "edit" but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Can you provide code where you are calling edit function...basically the flow

Comment: So you are first selecting item by clicking <li and putting it in  currentItem and then you are editing the form right

Comment: Yes.

This is the code from the TodoItems Component:

  `<li key={item.key}>
        {item.text}
        <DropdownButton variant="secondary" bssize="small" id="dropdown-item-button-custom" size="sm"title="">
          <Dropdown.Item as="button" onClick={() => this.props.deleteItem(item.key)}> Delete</Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item as="button" onClick={() => this.props.editItem(item.key)}> Edit</Dropdown.Item>
        </DropdownButton>
      </li>`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your state, it should be `this.state.currentItem.text`

```
this.state = {
      items: [],
      currentItem: {
        text: '',
        key: '',
      },
```

You can update your state like this:

```
editItem = key => {
  console.log(key)
  this.setState(prevState=> ({ currentItem: {key, text: 'edit'})
}
```

Comment: This solves the issue of returning undefined but now the log is empty (i did enter some text)

Comment: Ok, in that case it seems that your state isn't being set correctly. Check that part of the logic (maybe add it to your question).

Comment: What part of my logic could be wrong? this.state.currentItem.text does return empty. Can you help me here?

Comment: Where/how are you setting `state.currentItem` or `state.currentItem.text`?

Comment: That's done on the handleInput Function:

  `handleInput = e => {
    const itemText = e.target.value
    const currentItem = { text: itemText, key: Date.now() }
    //MongoDB: eigenen Key (DB) verwenden
    this.setState({
      currentItem,
    })
  }`

Comment: That looks OK, I think you might need to add more code to your question... How is `handleInput` being called, for example?

Answer (score 1):

Your console log is wrong it should be `console.log(this.state.currentItem.text);`

Comment: `console.log(this.state.currentItem.text);` returns empty value for me. Any idea? I tried different approaches but none works

Comment: It returns an empty item because you initialize it empty in the constructor.
And in your editItem function you don't target the good state when you edit the state

Comment: Can you specify what a good state is? I googled it but didn't find anything. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The console should be **`this.state.currentItem.text`** . Maybe you should get a cup of coffee or a little walk before you sit to code again :)

Comment: Thanks. Tried it but the return is empty. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your edit function should probably look like this. You have to setState the whole currentItem state.

```
editItem = key => {
  this.setState({
    currentItem: {
       text: 'edit',
       key,
     }
  })
}
```